# bash cat multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cat

I am trying to `cat` three files and obtain and insert a newline `\n` 
after each file ,I thought of using something like :

```
cat f1 f2 f3|tr "\EOF" "\n"
```

without success.

What is the easiest way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
cat f1 <(echo) f2 <(echo) f3 <(echo)
```

or

```
perl -pe 'eof&&s/$/\n/' a b c
```

Comment: +1 for the `<(echo)` idiom.  Somehow I missed that in more than a decade of bash scripting!

Comment: have a look to `process substitution`, may not work on systems lacking /dev/fd files

Answer (score 9):

`EOF` *isn't* a character, not even CTRL-D - that's just the usual terminal method for indicating EOF on interactive input. So you can't use tools for translating characters to somehow modify it.

For this simple case, the *easiest* way is to stop worrying about trying to do it in a single `cat` :-)

```
cat f1; echo; cat f2; echo; cat f3
```

will do the trick just fine. Any larger number of files may be worthy of a script but I can't see the necessity for this small case.

If you want to combine all those streams for further processing, simply run them in a subshell:

```
( cat f1; echo; cat f2; echo; cat f3 ) | some_process
```

Answer (score 9):

As soon as you `cat` the files, there will be no EOF in between them, and no other way to find the border, so I'd suggest something like `for file in f1 f2 f3; do cat $file; echo; done` or, with indentation,

```
for file in f1 f2 f3; do
    cat $file;
    echo;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

i was having a similar problem, what worked best for me i my situation was:

```
grep "" file1 file2 file3 | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tight to `cat` tool only, use `bat` https://github.com/sharkdp/bat.

```bash
bat -p file1 file2 file3
```

also, if you have dynamic files count, one can use wildcard:

```bash
bat -p *.extension
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
find f1 f2 f3 | xargs cat
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because it's exactly the same as `cat f1 f2 f3`. I suggest you to fix or remove this answer.